# PageView.animateToPage not working for elasticInOut Animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I've a PageView with 3 pages(initial page:0). What I'm intending to do is to create a 3 section page with a back button which only displays if not in the initial page. 
The code used to navigate to the other pages from initial page. (Working without issues)

```
pageController.animateToPage(1,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.easeIn);
}),
```

[easeIn animation, 500ms duration]

The Code used for the back button

```
pageController.animateToPage(pageController.initialPage,
   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
   curve: Curves.elasticInOut 
);
```

[elasticInOut animation, 500ms duration]

When trying to go back from page(2) to page(0) this won't work, however it works fine while going back from page(1) to page(0).

**What Seems To Fix It?**

- Reducing duration to 250ms or less
- Changing curve to easeIn
- Changing animateToPage to jumpTopage

So is this a known limitation of Flutter or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think this happens with any curve that initially produces a negative value (like Curves.elasticInOut). I can't pinpoint the exact line (I suspect it's in applyUserOffset from ScrollPositionWithSingleContext), but negative values seem to be treated as if the animation has already completed. It may occasionally work with smaller/faster animations that produce values that are "less negative" (or close enough to zero).

Curves.linear or Curves.ease* don't produce negative values, so they should work consistently.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the PageView scroll-behavior to Cupertino (which allows negative values) seems to fix the problem

```dart
PageView(
   controller: controller,
   scrollBehavior: CupertinoScrollBehavior(),
   children: [
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add   `physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),` in page view .
as friends said it is because of negative value .
i hope it will help you.